# Alternaion with quantifies in gregexpr and str_extract_all function

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Alternaion with quantifies in `gregexpr` and `str_extract_all` function

```
require(stringr)
gregexpr(pattern = "(h|a)*", "xxhx")
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 0 0 1 0
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

str_extract_all(pattern = "(h|a)*", "xxhx")
[[1]]
[1] ""  ""  "h" ""  ""
```

why `gregexpr` indicates 3 voids while `str_extract_all` indicates 4 voids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the difference between how TRE (`gregexpr`) and ICU (`str_extract_all`) regex engines deal with empty (also called "zero length") regex matches. TRE regex advances the regex index after a zero length match, while ICU allows testing the same position twice.

It becomes obvious what positions are tried by both engines if you use replacing functions:

```
> gsub("(h|a)*", "-\\1", "xxhx")
[1] "-x-x-hx-"
> str_replace_all("xxhx", "(h|a)*", "-\\1")
[1] "-x-x-h-x-"
```

The TRE engine matched `h` and moved the index after `x` while ICU engine matched `h` and stopped right after `h` before `x` to match the empty location before it.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor for helping me out!